# Game Screeps - Snapshots

Tags: javascript, screeps

I'm playing Screeps (http://screeps.com/) Simulation Room mode. I've tested some stuff and I don't want to lose my progress.

Can I make snapshots and save my room state on the Simulation Room mode, so I don't have to start all over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written on the docs (http://www.screeps.com/docs/Room.php), it's not possible:

> makeSnapshot([description])
>
> Create a room snapshot with all objects
> currently present in the room. Room snapshots are saved in your
> account so that you can later check out if something happened in the
> game when you were offline. **Not available in the Simulation Room.**

Answer (score 0):

If you clear your browser (not only using CCleaner) you will lost your work!

So, you should backup your cookies for the side of demo game before cleaning. 
I am using Chrome for this game in Windows 7. Cookies directory is:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage
```

and file names are:

```
http_screeps.com_0.localstorage
http_screeps.com_0.localstorage-journal
```

Now you can copy back your cookies after cleaning process.